# How to add Back Button functionality in a VisualForce page?

Tags: visualforce

I want to add "Back" button functionality on my VF page. As javascript:history.back()  does not work in VisualForce page, is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="doRedirect();"/>                
          </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function doRedirect(){
                    window.history.back();
                }

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagereference class. Something like this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!back}"/>

Public pagereference back() {
Pagereference pg = new Pagereference ('/apex/NewPageName');
pg.setRedirect (true);
return pg;
}
```

More information on the class can be found here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm

Comment: My redirection page is not vf page.I have Mass update button on Case which is overrided with VF page. So, now when I used a cancel button it should redirect back to the Case tab of list view which i have selected (same like browser back functionality).